# Removing duplicate indices from mysql database with priority

Tags: mysql, indexing, foreign-keys, database-optimization

I am making a procedure for optimizing indices of my databases and it will take me long. So I want to confirm if it is feasible to do? And not already done otherwise want to get it.

1. I want to read all indices from all tables.
2. I want to drop all other indices on fields which are primary key
3. After doing above. The fields which are still indexed as unique. I want to drop all other indices on them
4. The fields which are neither primary nor unique. I want to keep only one index on each and drop all other indices

I am curious Why MYSQL allows unique index on a primary key field? Can it make any useful difference?

**Question** : 
I need guidance/query/procedure to remove all non useful indices with the hierarchy mentioned in my above 4 points

**Update 1:** I will keep my work updating [**Here on SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f438/9). At the moment it is just beginning. However you can see on this link that there are four fields and 8 indices. I want just 3 of them and drop all others. I need only 1st, 3rd and 4th. According to my above 4 points.

**Update 2** : I got excellent answer by eggayal. First link he gave is the pure sql solution. I tried it [**Here at Link2**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ba8a/4). It gave me undesired output. Output of link2 can be compared by looking into [**Link1 here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ba8a/2)

**Desired output Is**

```
    COLUMN_NAMES    REDUNDANT_INDEXES
1   auth_id         `auth_id_3`,`auth_id_2`,`auth_id`
2   id              `id_2`,`id_3`
3   subject         `subject_1`
```

**Faults in th output of query** in [**Link2**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ba8a/4)

Row1: auth_id is not shown as redundant index because It has nothing to do (compare) with unique key `auth_id_4` on the same field. But I need it because I don't need this index when same column has a unique index as well

Row2 :  I will like to say all other indices redundant when there exists primary key
index on some column

Row3 : All right

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're talking about?  For instance `show index from ExampleTableName`

Comment: Yes I am going to update sqlfiddle link. And doing the same as you said. `show idex from` and then save these indices before dropping

Comment: Given only a database schema, there is no single "optimum indexing strategy".  Indeed, it's meaningless to refer to indexing at all without knowing the queries that are to be performed on the data.  Indexes are a trade-off: they slow down write operations (insertions/updates) but speed up read operations (selection); therefore the "optimum" indexing strategy for you will depend on the proportion of reads to writes that your application performs.  It also depends on the actual queries, as different queries will benefit from different indexes.

Comment: @eggyal. Right I understood you. But can it be useful to have same index multiple times on the same field for reading/select? You can see my sqlfiddle link

Comment: I can't see any benefit in the multiple (identical) indexes on `(auth_id)` in your example `articles_tb` table: the `UNIQUE` key `auth_id_3` alone should be sufficient.

Comment: @eggyal yes that is what I need to do. This database I have got and I need to remove unuseful indices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made an application in c#. It removes duplicate indices according to your priority, Hope it would help

It might need much improvements but what I know is... It does not remove only those duplicate indices which are involved in primary(composite) and foreign key at a time (which should not be usually good approach)

[**Here is download link for complete application with source**](https://khukkw.bn1.livefilestore.com/y1pBkAeYW4Ge77Vmx4qDzRk-vn2P6fR5iYnze6hAWPMYYjzs4uibX9dJ4WcHnD-s2iR0YsS8DRaaCK6xyHwlqMXng/duplicateIndexRemover.rar?download&psid=1)

Following is the main file of above link

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace duplicateIndexRemover
{
public class duplicateIndexRemover
{

    static List<string> toDrop;
    public string main(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dgv, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dgv1, string dbName)
    {            
        try
        {
            toDrop = new List<string>();
            List<table> tbs = new List<table>();
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            string cnStr = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=" + dbName + ";UID=root;";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(cnStr);
            MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT Table_Name,Column_Name,Index_Name,NON_UNIQUE
            FROM information_schema.STATISTICS
            WHERE table_schema = '" + dbName + "' order by Table_Name,Column_Name,Index_Name";
            MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(dt);
            dgv.DataSource = dt;
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                dt1.Columns.Add(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName);

            table tb = new table();
            column cl = new column();
            index dx = new index();
            tb.nam = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            cl = addColumn(dt, tb, 0);
            tbs.Add(tb);

            for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (tb.nam != dt.Rows[i][0].ToString())
                {
                    // 1st column of (current) t_th table
                    tb = new table();
                    tb.nam = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                    cl = addColumn(dt, tb, i);
                    tbs.Add(tb);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (cl.nam != dt.Rows[i][1].ToString())
                        cl = addColumn(dt, tb, i);
                    else
                    {

                        // Duplicate Indices
                        // But this one may be primary/unique key
                        // Then it would not be good to make a drop statement for this index here
                        // It may be improvable, but i can not apply as well condition here if it is not primary key
                        addIndex(dt, cl, i);
                    }
                }
            }
            makeDropStatements(tbs, dt1);

            dgv1.DataSource = dt1;
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i < toDrop.Count; i++)
            {
                cmd.CommandText = toDrop[i];
                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }
                catch//(Exception ex)
                {
                    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Table : " + dt1.Rows[i][0] + " Column : " + dt1.Rows[i][1] + "\n\n" + ex.Message);
                }
            }

            cmd.CommandText = @"select table_name from information_schema.STATISTICS
            WHERE table_schema = '" + dbName + "' group by table_name,column_name";
            DataTable dg = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(dg);

            string msg = " Total Number of Indices : " + dt.Rows.Count;
            msg += "\t Droppable Indices : " + toDrop.Count;
            msg += "\t Total Number of Indexed Columns : " + dg.Rows.Count;
            return msg;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }

    private static column addColumn(DataTable dt, table tb, int i)
    {
        column cl = new column();
        // 1st index of i_th column of t_th table
        cl.nam = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
        addIndex(dt, cl, i);
        tb.cols.Add(cl);
        return cl;
    }

    private static void addIndex(DataTable dt, column cl, int i)
    {
        index dx = new index();
        dx.nam = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
        dx.non_unique = Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[i][3]);
        cl.indices.Add(dx);
    }


    private static void makeDropStatements(List<table> tbs, DataTable dt1)
    {
        bool chekd;
        List<index> temp;
        for (int t = 0; t < tbs.Count; t++)
        {                
            for (int i = 0; i < tbs[t].cols.Count; i++)
            {                    
                temp = tbs[t].cols[i].indices;
                if (temp.Count > 1)
                {

                    chekd = false;
                    for (int j = 0; j < temp.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (temp[j].nam == "PRIMARY")
                        {
                            getToDropIndices(tbs[t].nam, tbs[t].cols[i].nam, temp, j, dt1);
                            chekd = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!chekd)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < temp.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if (!temp[j].non_unique)
                            {
                                getToDropIndices(tbs[t].nam, tbs[t].cols[i].nam, temp, j, dt1);
                                chekd = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (!chekd)
                    {
                        getToDropIndices(tbs[t].nam, tbs[t].cols[i].nam, temp, 0, dt1);
                        chekd = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void getToDropIndices(string tbl, string col, List<index> sublist, int nt, DataTable dt1)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nt; j++)
        {
            toDrop.Add("alter table `" + tbl + "` drop index " + sublist[j].nam);
            dt1.Rows.Add(dt1.NewRow());
            int r = dt1.Rows.Count - 1;
            dt1.Rows[r][0] = tbl;
            dt1.Rows[r][1] = col;
            dt1.Rows[r][2] = sublist[j].nam;
        }
        for (int j = nt + 1; j < sublist.Count; j++)
        {
            toDrop.Add("alter table `" + tbl + "` drop index " + sublist[j].nam);
            dt1.Rows.Add(dt1.NewRow());
            int r = dt1.Rows.Count - 1;
            dt1.Rows[r][0] = tbl;
            dt1.Rows[r][1] = col;
            dt1.Rows[r][2] = sublist[j].nam;
        }
    }
}

public class table
{
    public List<column> cols =new List<column>();
    public string nam = "";
}

public class column
{
    public List<index> indices = new List<index>();
    public string nam = "";
}

public class index
{
    public string nam = "";
    public bool non_unique;
}
}
```

You may ignore/remove gridviews they are just for showing your indices. You just need to call main function

Answer (score 2):

Roland Bouman wrote a [blog article](http://www.oreillynet.com/databases/blog/2006/09/_finding_redundant_indexes_usi.html) on this very subject, showing a pure SQL solution.

A [quick search on Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+duplicate+index+finder) also churned up:

- [`DuplicateIndexFinder.java`](http://www.jroller.com/dschneller/resource/DuplicateIndexFinder.java);
- A similar tool written in Perl that was part of [maatkit](http://code.google.com/p/maatkit/), now [Percona Toolkit](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit/); and
- [`mysqlindexanalyzer`](http://code.google.com/p/mysqlindexanalyzer/).

Comment: Thanks eggayal. Are you sure it is serving the same purpose as I need in my question. First links seems convincing and I am going to view all. Thanks +1 for your help. Hope it will be the acceptable and the desired solution exactly or nearly according to the question :)

Comment: @Sami: All of these solutions were created in response to Peter Zaitsev's article [Duplicate indexes and redundant indexes](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/17/duplicate-indexes-and-redundant-indexes/), to which Roland Bouman refers in his blog.  As you will see there, Peter was documenting precisely the problem you describe above; therefore, whilst I haven't verified each of the solutions, they ought to attempt exactly what you need.

Comment: Plus Thanks for guidance about google search. And information_scema.statisitics is very very useful thing I cam to know today from your first link

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I see in the link there do seem to be a number of extraneous indexes like these:

```
KEY `auth_id_2` (`auth_id`),
KEY `auth_id_4` (`auth_id`),
KEY `auth_id_5` (`auth_id`),
KEY `auth_id_6` (`auth_id`)
```

I thought maybe they were built in different ways.  For instance one could be a BTREE and another a HASH, which could potentially serve some purpose.  But they're all the same according to SHOW.  Removing the extra identical ones should not be an issue.

There is a purpose to having, for instance, all three of these though:

```
KEY `articleid` (`artid`),
KEY `artSub` (`artSub`),
KEY `comments_ibfk_3` (`artSub`,`artid`)
```

Building the index on two columns is not necessarily the same as building two separate indexes on one.

Comment: Surprised to see a vote. I had tried my best to make this question very clear before posting it. But I need to be told that what is so confusing? I would try to make that clear. But actual question is how to remove multiple indices with the priority I mentioned in my first 4 points